# How to call the next row of data that corresponds to my condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am working on an inventory managing project, which is used for people borrowing and returning materials so that I can keep track of them and avoid losing.

Currently, I have made a button that runs under a script as seen below. Basically, this button searches the database (all history of materials borrowed and returned) using NAME and ITEM NAME, which are data for cell "C7" and "C9".

The searchRecord function works very well except it only gives me the first row of data that corresponds to the NAME and ITEM NAME typed by the user. I would like to add an upward and downward arrow to call data in other rows in my database.

```
function searchRecord() {
  
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Teacher's Input Form"); 
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Borrow/Return Database"); 
    
  var str       = shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue();
  var str2      = shUserForm.getRange("C9").getValue();

  var values    = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  var valuesFound=false; 
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
    {
    var rowValue = values[i]; 
   
  
    if (rowValue[1] == str && rowValue[2] == str2){
           
      shUserForm.getRange("C4").setValue(rowValue[0]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C11").setValue(rowValue[3]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C13").setValue(rowValue[4]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C15").setValue(rowValue[5]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C17").setValue(rowValue[6]);
      return; //come out from the search function
      
      }
  }


if(valuesFound==false){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("No record found!");
 }


}
```

So here is an example. A person named Bob may borrow 2 tables today. Then, he may borrow 2 more tables tomorrow. In my database, there will be a record of him borrowing the same item twice, yet when I use the search function, it only calls the history of his first borrowing.

Can anyone teach me a good way to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide a screen-cap of that Teacher's Input Form, so that we know how you are going to display the search result.

Anyway, in this example, the result data will be placed from A1 to anywhere, according to the length of you search result.

You can change the output location of the results by editing line 14.

```js
function searchRecord() {
  const myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const shUserForm = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Teacher's Input Form"); 
  const datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Borrow/Return Database"); 
  const str = shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue();
  const str2 = shUserForm.getRange("C9").getValue();
  const values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  
  const result = values
    .filter(row => row[1] == str && row[2] == str2)
    .map(row => [row[0],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6]]);

  if (!result.length) SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No record found!");
  else shUserForm.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```